# Can keys be rearranges after dictionary creation?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am curious if key's can be rearranged after the dictionary has been created.

I would like to first enumerate the total number of values behind each key and then shuffle the order so they may be printed off from largest to smallest.

Say:

```
x= {'ONE': ['foo'], 'THREE': ['up', 'side', 'down'], 'TWO': ['hot', 'mess']}
```

Can I get it to look like, or at least print off in the order of THREE, TWO, ONE?

Could I combine `.get` with a `len()` somehow to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is relevant here, but just in case: If you're going to be continually modifying the dictionary and iterating it, you may want to use an automatically-sorted dictionary (like the one in [`blist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/)), instead of sorting it each time after modifying it (or before iterating it). The reason I don't think this is relevant is that you're apparently building the whole thing at once and never modifying it again, in which case David Robinson's answer (and/or Ashwini Chaudhary's comment to that answer) is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I like to read up on new packages. However, you are right  this script takes some output and places it in a dictionary once. I then preform all downstream actions using the dictionary as a input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary keys do not have an ordering in Python, so there is no way to reorder them.

If you do want to print it out in order of the list size, however, you could show it as a list of tuples:

```
sorted(x.items(), key=lambda t: -len(t[1]))
# [('THREE', ['up', 'side', 'down']), ('TWO', ['hot', 'mess']), ('ONE', ['foo'])]
```

Comment: And pass this sorted list to an `OrderedDict` to get a sorted dict.

Comment: Instead of negating, you can pass `reverse=True`. And if you operate only on the keys, you can get rid of the lambda entirely: `sorted(x, key=len, reverse=True)`.

Comment: @delnan: He didn't want it to operate on the keys, he wanted the longer lists (not the longer keys) to come first. (And it seems to me that adding `, reverse=True` is just less concise).

Comment: `reverse=True` is clearer/more explicit. And depending on what exactly one does, the keys are sufficient (though probably not in OP's case, yeah).

Comment: This should work for me, I (being new to python) have created a script that works in dictionaries and only dictionaries. So I think my "vision" has been a little narrow as to all the possible solutions I could have if I were to branch out form my comfort zone.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without an ordered dict:

```
x= {'ONE': ['foo'], 'THREE': ['up', 'side', 'down'], 'TWO': ['hot', 'mess']}
xkeys = sorted(x, key=lambda y: len(x[y])
for key in xkeys:
    print(x[key])
```

It doesn't reorder your dict but it is the same result. But as others have said dicts are unordered by definition in python. Ordered dict allows you to move elements to the end, also you can sort it on creation. Docs here: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.OrderedDict
So you could use the sorting recipe found there as well.

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[1])))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I had forget that dictionaries aren't ordered in virtual space. I have yet to work with `OrderedDict` so I'll look into that as well.

Comment: They are accessible just like normal dicts. so you can use them interchangeably for almost every situation (at least that I've ever run into). The docs provide a lot of extra data but the recipe I provided works well.

Comment: Yup, I am reading it now. I'll see if they are interchangeable now, most of my script uses normal dictionaries currently.